# How add a new {key:value} per array element merging others identically structured JSON with jq

Tags: json, linux, bash, jq

The current JSON database, the file `db.json`, is structured as:

```
[
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_1": "value_1.1",
      "key_2": "value_2.1"
    }
  },
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_1": "value_1.2",
      "key_2": "value_2.2"
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

So simply. The number of total elements in the array can vary.
I want to join the key that lies in several identically structured documents, the file `new.json`:

```
[
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_n": "value_1.N"
    }
  },
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_n": "value_2.N"
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

where the array in each JSON to be added certainly has the same number of elements present in the current database and where each "entry" element:
- it certainly contains no more than one single key.
- with certainty the key and its string value is always present.
- with certainty the key has a unique name compared to the keys already present in the database.

Therefore, after each jq execution, the expected result will be the addition to the database of the new key in the corresponding array element:

```
[
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_1": "value_1.1",
      "key_2": "value_1.2",
      "key_n": "value_1.N"
    }
  },
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_1": "value_2.1",
      "key_2": "value_2.2",
      "key_n": "value_2.N"
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

I use linux and want to do this with jq from a bash script.
My linux distribution provides jq 1.5 stable release (16 Aug 2015).

I have the feeling of asking something of trivial already extensively covered but I assure you: for two days now I have been applying the answers found in other very similar questions and I have not succeeded...

I can insert a new key with this technique which I found in many other *stack overflow* responses about merging:

```
jq -s --argfile db db.json 'map(reduce . as $new ({}; $db[] * $new[]))' new.json
```

but in this way only the last element remains in my `db.json` file..

```
[
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_1": "value_2.1",
      "key_2": "value_2.2",
      "key_n": "value_2.N"
    }
  }
]
```

while with the `+` operator:

```
jq -s --argfile db db.json 'reduce . as $new ({}; $db + $new)' new.json
```

the merging of the elements, as expected, is not achieved..

```
[
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_1": "value_1.1",
      "key_2": "value_1.2"
    }
  },
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_1": "value_2.1",
      "key_2": "value_2.2"
    }
  },
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_n": "value_1.N"
    }
  },
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_n": "value_2.N"
    }
  }
]
```

**RESULT UPDATE**
uhu, it seems that this command that I've just now tried does all the work correctly:

```
jq -s --argfile db db.json 'map($db[] * .[]) | unique_by(.foo)' new.json
```

`unique_by(.foo)` removes all recursion duplicates that I would have using the `*` operator only..
Does this seem to you a consistent technique to solve my question?

Comment: To simplify the answer I would probably have done well to specify a filename for JSON documents: then let's say that the database is called `db.json` and I want to merge the 'new.json' document.

Comment: The problem statement is clear enough but it would be helpful if you followed the [mcve] guidelines more closely, particularly with respect to “entry”.

Comment: @peak where does it say "Use consistent naming..."? I've seen that other questions often use 'foo' and that's fine here too. Do I have to change the question that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying your db.json and new.json to make them valid JSON, and adding the following filter to a file (update.jq):

```
reduce range(0;length) as $i (.;
  .[$i].foo += $new[$i].foo )
```

the following invocation:

```
jq --argfile new new.json -f update.jq db.json
```

produces:

```
[
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_1": "value_1.1",
      "key_2": "value_1.2",
      "key_n": "value_N.3"
    }
  },
  {
    "foo": {
      "key_1": "value_2.1",
      "key_2": "value_2.2",
      "key_n": "value_N.3"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I apologize for the format errors in the markup and subsequent repeated, inaccurate changes I made to my first question here in 'stack overflow'.

Comment: Could we define this technique that uses `range` as a `for i in {0..N}; do..` bash loop?... I had not addressed to solve in this sense because the speed of execution in my case quite matters (sorry, another point that I have forgotten to express..).
At the moment I don't still have a huge database with which to test the performances but it is possible to foresee that this technique doesn't have an impact on the execution times compared to the use of the `*` operator? - Anyway I've tested your solution and I confirm it works perfectly!!

Comment: After populating the array with more elements, I now see that your solution is the only one that really works as expected among all the techniques I so far tried (and 'unique_by()' doesn't work at all Increasing elements!), so I mark it immediately as 'accepted'.
Thanks @peak for all that you have taught me today!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your "bash loop" question is, but it is worth noting that even if new.json introduces many new "foo" keys, update.jq will handle them all properly and efficiently. Anything more complex than that probably deserves its own SO question.